# Выйдя из ванной, он поскользнулся и упал

Tags: синтаксис

**Выйдя из ванной**, он поскользнулся и упал.

Как я понимаю, это деепричастный оборот. А можно сказать, что это придаточное времени? Или сами обороты не могут строить придаточные предложения?

Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выйдя из ванной, он ПОскользнулся и упал.

Это деепричастный оборот в роли обстоятельства времени. Деепричастный оборот не может быть предложением, в том числе придаточным,  так как у него нет предикативной основы (подлежащего и сказуемого или одного главного члена)

Деепричастные конструкции считаются полупредикативными, так как деепричастие - это форма глагола, имеющего значение действия.

Answer (score 3):

*Выйдя из ванной* - это добавочное действие к основному (*поскользнулся, упал*), т.е. обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным оборотом. Деепричастные обороты не могут строить придаточные предложения.