# Деепричастные обороты

Tags: синтаксис

Примеры:

1) Он допил вторую чашку кофе и и затем обратился к прислуге, *попросив ее принести еще одну чашку.*

2) Она никому об этом не рассказала, *смиренно приняв еще один удар жизни в одиночку.*

3) Она вышла в коридор, *надеясь встретить его как бы случайно.*
(+еще один вопрос здесь: можно сказать, что *как бы случайно* это обстоятельство образа действия?)

Просто хочу уяснить для себя, правильно ли я понимаю. Как Вы мне в ранних вопросах объясняли, я поняла, что это деепричастные обороты. Синтаксически они не строят предложения, так? В моем раннем вопросе *Выйдя из ванной, он поскользнулся и упал* было указано, что *Выйдя из ванной* имеет роль обстоятельства времени. А в роли какого обстоятельства выступают вышеприведенные деепричастия?

Спасибо большое!

Comment: Всё правильно, деепричастные обороты. Обстоятельства образа действия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы знаете, деепричастия (и деепричастные обороты) играют синтаксическую роль обстоятельства, притом вид обстоятельства не определяется. Это просто обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным оборотом. И мне не очень понятна ваша мысль по поводу того, что деепричастные обороты не строят предложения. Как же не строят?! Строят! Это ведь тоже некий строительный материал.

Comment: я исходила из того, что мне сказала здесь Вера:
http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418662/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB  хотелось сказать, что деепр. обороты не используются самостоятельно. нельзя сказать "Выйдя из ванной ТОЧКА". A может я ее не так поняла?